# Inequality of *Problem From The Book* 19.20, but Using Integrals

Tags: integration, inequality

The problem is here:

> Let $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ be positive real numbers and let $S=a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n$. Prove that
> $$\frac 1n \sum_{1=1}^n\frac 1{a_i}+\frac{n(n-2)}S\ge\sum_{i\ne j}\frac1{S-a_i+a_j}$$

The chapter of this problem is *Solving Elementary Inequality Using Integrals*. After I typed the problem, I noted that this problem is **already asked** [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2681180/an-inequality-involving-n-positive-real-numbers-and-their-sum). The answer is using  Karamata's inequality, which... does not really fit the title of the chapter. This chapter suggested a technique: using $\int_0^1 x^{t-1}\mathrm dx=\frac 1t$ to transform the problems involving the fractions into polynomials. I tried this technique, let $y_i=x^{a_i-1/n}$, and we have, before integral as $\int_0^1 \dots\mathrm dx$, the inequality should be
$$\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^n+n(n-2)y_1y_2\dots y_n\ge y_1y_2\dots y_n\sum_{i\ne j}\frac{y_i}{y_j}$$
and I don't know  how to continue from here... or, is there another integration method other than the techneque above? Many thanks!

Comment: The resulting inequality is true.

Comment: @RiverLi Thank you for your comment. Would you like to write an answer to this? I believe it is true, but I cannot prove it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Fact 1**: Let $y_i > 0, \forall i$. Then
$$\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^n + n(n - 1)\prod_{i=1}^n y_i
\ge \prod_{i=1}^n y_i \sum_{i=1}^n y_i \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{y_i}. \tag{1}$$
(The proof is given [1], Ch. 5, page 249.)

From Fact 1, letting $y_i = x^{a_i - 1/n}, \forall i$, we integrate $\int_0^1 \cdots \mathrm{d}x$ both sides of (1) to get the desired result.

---

*Remarks*: For $n = 3$, (1) is just 3 degree Schur.
For $n = 4$, (1) is
$$x^4 + y^4 + z^4 + w^4 + 12xyzw
\ge (x + y + z + w)(xyz + yzw + zwx + wxy).$$
(I came to know this inequality in AoPS, known as one of Vasc's inequalities.)

---

*Reference*

[1] Vasile Cirtoaje, "Algebraic Inequalities-Old and New Methods," 2006.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I am really sorry that currently I don't have access to the reference source... Would you like to present the proof here? I am really sorry for making you doing me my favor again...

Comment: @JetfiRex Do you have access to this link: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/VasileCirtoaje.pdf?

Comment: I can open it, thank you very much!

Comment: @JetfiRex You are welcome.